# Is there a way in karma testing to check whether providers array have all the required services injected?

Tags: angular

While committing the code, i somehow missed to add the service in providers array, but i have added it in providers array of spec file. So the `ng test` passes all the test cases.

Is there any way to check if the providers array in the component have all the required services injected ?

component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css'],
    providers: []
})
```

spec:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    imports: [],
    providers : [DatePipe],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```